# When do GTD orders actually expire

Tags: fix-protocol

If a "new order single" order is GTD, meaning that it expires lets say 90 days from now, do GTD orders traditionally have a time stamp component or just date?  So if I am placing a GTD order at 10 am, for 90 days, and I do not specify a timestamp, it makes sense to me that this order would expire in 90 days, at 10:00:01 am.
And if I am placing a 90 day GTD order and I am specifically indicating timestamp of 11:46am, I expect that it will expire at 11:46:01 -- or something like that.  Does it make sense?

I am having a discussion with someone where they are trying to convince me that the order will expire in 90 days at the end of the day --- and that makes no sense, its counter-intuitive.
Thank u

Comment: Depends on the counter party. Some support intra day expiry, some don't. Some support expiry at certain events e.g. after an auction. In general end of day is pretty much the default case in my opinion.

Comment: BTW your 10 am example does not make sense. I never encountered this where a broker would expire the GTD order based on the time it was entered

Comment: This is why I am asking whats "customary" :)

Answer (score 3):

As with all things FIX, it depends on your counterparty.

The default FIX message dictionary is at best a suggestion, which brokers can and usually do use in varied and weird ways.  Perhaps the FIX docs may specify what it "ought" to be, but it doesn't really matter out in the wild.

**Never trust anything but the counterparty's docs.**

Answer (score 0):

Usually depends on the counterparty so worth checking their specifications as it will be clearer there as to what they support, If you are just doing some code/testing yourself, then using end of day is fine. EOD is pretty standard, I've yet to encounter GTD expiring based on the time it was entered.

Answer (score 0):

> Never trust anything but the counterparty's docs.

@grant-birchmeier is very right in saying this.

One thing worth highlighting is that a GTD `TimeInForce` can have either an `ExpireDate`, or an `ExpireTime` - the latter is explicit in saying exactly when you want our order out (if your counterparty supports it!)

This is what the [FIX Online Specification](https://www.fixtrading.org/online-specification/business-area-trade/) says about this point:

> The underlying business assumption of orders that can trade over multiple days, such as TimeInForce(59) = 1 (GTC) and 6 (GTD) orders expiring on a future trading date (henceforth referred to as GT orders) is that a GT order that is not fully executed and has not been canceled and has not expired on a given day remains good for the broker to execute the following day. **Note that the concept of “day” is determined by the market convention, which will be security specific.** ... When the ExpireDate(432) or ExpireTime(132) of an order with TimeInForce(59) = 6 (GTD) is reached, or an order with TimeInForce(59) = 1 (GTC) reaches a maximum age, the order is considered expired and the broker may optionally send an ExecutionReport(35=8) with ExecType(150) = C (Expired) and OrdStatus(39) = C (Expired).

Answer (score -1):

Good till date ( i.e. `tag 59=6`) comes with conditional `tag 432`. Meaning if you are sending New order single with `59=6`, `432=90` days from today's date then our orders will be in order book till EOD of 90th days. on EOD your order will be expired.

If you want to keep your order active until 1PM of 90th day then use tag `126=Expirytime`  (in UTC) along with tag `59=6`. so your order will expire on 1.01 PM with status `150=C` and `39=C`.